# Add enclosure tag to rss newsfeed TYPO3

Tags: php, rss, typo3, extbase, tt-news

Hi I'm using tx_chnewsfeeds_pi1 feed. I need to show the images of items in feed. How it is possible? I need

```
<enclosure url="http://www.scripting.com/mp3s/weatherReportSuite.mp3" [^] length="12216320" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

Comment: I undeleted the question

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Class `tx_chnewsfeeds_pi1` only fills the template with `###LINK###` and `###DESCRIPTION###` for each news item and nothing else.

Comment: It is ok.But How to redesign the xml file file generated when clicking on the link?